# How to call a method just after every log in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

We are migrating from Log41.x to Log4j2.x. We had some custom logging in log4j1, where we were putting some log arguments in ThreadLocal for some of the logs and those arguments picked by our logger and sent to the appender. the appender was also custom appender, that formats the log message to Json format. After every log, those arguments are cleared from the thread local.

The same thing I want to achieve in log4j2 to support our old logging system.

I have tried in log4j2 by creating a custom LoggerConfig class by overriding log method, there I clearing the arguments from thread local.

To include the custom Logger config plugin I am setting the {log4j.plugin.packages} the system property to my customLoggerConfig class package.
But new logger config is not picked by log4j2 configuration.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginElement;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message;


@Plugin(name = "customLogger", category = "Core", printObject = true)
public class CustomLoggerConfig extends LoggerConfig
{

public CustomLoggerConfig(final String name, final List<AppenderRef> appenders, final Filter filter,
        final Level level, final boolean additive, final Property[] properties, final Configuration config, final boolean includeLocation)
{
    super(name, appenders, filter, level, additive, null, config, includeLocation);
}

@Override
public void log(final String loggerName, final String fqcn, final Marker marker, final Level level,
        final Message data, final Throwable t)
{
    super.log(loggerName, fqcn, marker, level, data, t);
    clearLogArg();
}

@Override
public void log(final LogEvent event)
{
    super.log(event);
    clearLogArg();
}

public void clearLogArg()
{
    LogArg.clear();
}

@PluginFactory
public static LoggerConfig createLogger(@PluginAttribute(value = "additivity", defaultBoolean = true) final boolean additivity,
        @PluginAttribute("level") final Level level,
        @Required(message = "Loggers cannot be configured without a name") @PluginAttribute("name") final String loggerName,
        @PluginAttribute("includeLocation") final String includeLocation,
        @PluginElement("AppenderRef") final AppenderRef[] refs,
        @PluginElement("Properties") final Property[] properties,
        @PluginConfiguration final Configuration config,
        @PluginElement("Filter") final Filter filter
    ) {
        return new CustomLoggerConfig(loggerName, Arrays.asList(refs), filter, level, additivity, properties, config,
            includeLocation(includeLocation, config));
}

protected static boolean includeLocation(final String includeLocationConfigValue, final Configuration configuration)
{
    if (includeLocationConfigValue == null)
    {
        LoggerContext context = null;
        if (configuration != null)
        {
            context = configuration.getLoggerContext();
        }
        if (context != null)
        {
            return !(context instanceof AsyncLoggerContext);
        }
        else
        {
            return !AsyncLoggerContextSelector.isSelected();
        }
    }
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(includeLocationConfigValue);
}
}
```

Comment: You can try AOP (aspect oriented programming) to create aspect which will be invoked after loj4j2 log methods